# Hyper-V not allowing the mouse in Windows Vista

Tags: mouse, virtual-machine, windows-vista, hyper-v

OK, I am having a problem setting up a virtual machine in Hyper-V, I’m not getting the use of the mouse. When I connect to the machine from Hyper-V and click somewhere I get:

***Virtual Machine Connection***

***Mouse not captured in Remote Desktop session.
The mouse is available in a Remote Desktop session when integration services are installed in the guest operating system.***

If I try the same from Virtual Machine Manager I get:

***Virtual Machine Connection***

***The mouse is unavailable in a Remote Desktop session when virtual guest services are not installed in the guest operating system.***

The operating system is Vista Ultimate x86 Service Pack 2.

I have installed the integration services disk (Action | Insert Integration Services Setup Disk). This runs through the installation, says it was successful and prompts for a restart. After the restart I log in, click on something and get the same error above.

I have been Googling and as a result I have tried:

1. Detecting the HAL
2. Adding a 2nd CPU
3. Installed all available Windows updates
4. Trying installing the integration services again by running as administrator
5. Building a new Vista machine
6. Importing a Vista .vhd file from VirtualBox

Nothing. No joy.

Does anyone know how I can allow my Vista machine to accept the mouse?

Thank you.

Comment: OK, finally I remembered an old decommissioned Virtual Machine server that had a Vista VM on it. I grabbed the vhd file from that and imported it to my new VM server and I finally have a Vista VM on which I can use the mouse.

Comment: If anyone has any ideas why I can't add the mouse to a new Vista machine I would still be interested.

Comment: That OS is your Hyper-V server running?

Answer (score 1):

This might sound trivial, but have you tried enabling "Guest Services" on the Vista VM? Here is how you can do it:
* From Hyper-V manager, right click on the Vista VM and go to Settings
* Management > Integration Services > Check "Guest Services".

If that does not help, let me know the version of your Windows host and also the result of following Powershell cmdlet (You need to execute this when VM is running):

```
Get-VM -Name <Your VM Name> | Select IntegrationServicesVersion, IntegrationServicesState
```

Typically, attaching the ISO file from Host's "C:\Windows\System32\vmguest.iso" and running the Setup from inside the VM should enable Mouse on Vista VMs. This is automatically done when you do "Insert Integration Services Setup Disk" action.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it is not too late. First of all, you need to turn off the VM, and change the OS type to Vista in VM summary. Then you are allowed to install Virtual Guest Services. After installation, issue disappeared.

Basically I think the issue is from the fact that Hyper-V was not to identify the OS correctly.

Comment: Where do you change the **OS type**? What menu, context, or action item are you looking at?

Answer (score 0):

I added all the hyper-v system devices in manually. Check with another working VM to see what system devices are not shown. Re-started and it worked fine.